# Windows 8 wakes from sleep immediately with errors regarding "memory type range registers (MTRRs)"

Tags: windows-8, sleep, netbios

After an arbitrary, but small amount of time, my computer wakes back up after going to sleep. I have attempted desperately to solve this issue, short of contacting any official support or re-installing Windows. I do not remember the problem occurring when I first installed Windows, but I am not sure. The machine is self-built running Windows 8 Pro.

These are the events that occur with sleep (in order):

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        BROWSER
Date:          1/1/2013 1:52:23 PM
Event ID:      8033
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
The browser has forced an election on network \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{38B1E9D2-97C3-46D5-A867-3B8B3C95D6B6} because a master browser was stopped.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BROWSER" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">8033</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T18:52:23.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8968</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{38B1E9D2-97C3-46D5-A867-3B8B3C95D6B6}</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Next:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          1/1/2013 1:52:23 PM
Event ID:      42
Task Category: (64)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: Application API
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>42</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>64</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000004</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T18:52:23.839972400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8969</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6192" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">4</Data>
    <Data Name="Flags">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Next:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          1/1/2013 1:52:24 PM
Event ID:      137
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      (4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
The system firmware has changed the processor's memory type range registers (MTRRs) across a sleep state transition (S4). This can result in reduced resume performance.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>137</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000004</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T18:52:24.616270300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8970</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6192" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SleepState">4</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Next:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General
Date:          1/1/2013 2:10:25 PM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Time
User:          N/A
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
The system time has changed to ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎01T19:10:25.500000000Z from ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎01T18:52:24.616366600Z.

Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" Guid="{A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T19:10:25.499903700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8971</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6192" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="NewTime">2013-01-01T19:10:25.500000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="OldTime">2013-01-01T18:52:24.616366600Z</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">2</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Next:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          1/1/2013 2:10:25 PM
Event ID:      131
Task Category: (33)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
Firmware S3 times. ResumeCount: 13, FullResume: 473, AverageResume: 472
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>131</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>33</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000004</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T19:10:25.825934500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8972</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="6192" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ResumeCount">13</Data>
    <Data Name="FullResume">473</Data>
    <Data Name="AverageResume">472</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Finally:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
Date:          1/1/2013 2:10:27 PM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      andrew-pc
Description:
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎01T18:52:23.452847300Z
Wake Time: ‎2013‎-‎01‎-‎01T19:10:25.849947800Z

Wake Source: Unknown
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter" Guid="{CDC05E28-C449-49C6-B9D2-88CF761644DF}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-01T19:10:27.826143400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8973</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{6A001E78-384D-427C-BC09-CB6A4CD14750}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="1580" ThreadID="4592" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>andrew-pc</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SleepTime">2013-01-01T18:52:23.452847300Z</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTime">2013-01-01T19:10:25.849947800Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SleepDuration">430</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeDuration">350</Data>
    <Data Name="DriverInitDuration">317</Data>
    <Data Name="BiosInitDuration">866</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberWriteDuration">1426</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberReadDuration">0</Data>
    <Data Name="HiberPagesWritten">150823</Data>
    <Data Name="Attributes">16641</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetState">4</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceType">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceTextLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeSourceText">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerOwnerLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerContextLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="NoMultiStageResumeReason">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerOwner">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="WakeTimerContext">
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I can provide any other system specifications upon request. Many people seem to be encountering the issue with Windows 8, with various solutions failing to resolve my issue. My hunch is that it is a driver or motherboard issue, any troubleshooting help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

In a further attempt to solve the problem, retrieving a *Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report* with `Powercfg –energy` during an induced sleep/wake cycle unsurfaced the following "error:"

```
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The program has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
 Requesting Process \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe
```

([Full report](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2725001/energy-report.html))

Disabling *Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service* in *Services* has so far not relieved the issue, as I still find my computer awake moments after I sleep it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through trial and error I finally found that disabling the network adapter from being able to wake the computer under *Device Manager* immediately  cured the issue. My PC no longer wakes up from sleep unexpectedly!

Comment: I hope that you mean it no longer wakes up from sleep when you don't want it to; be careful what you wish for!

Comment: This does not work with me.

Comment: @paulo Make a separate question with more details and diagnostics.

Comment: For me, it was my PCIe Wi-Fi card that caused it. Ethernet was no problem.